# Please recommend a good Slime tutorial or screencast

Tags: java, emacs, clojure, slime

My adventures in Java have lead me to look into Clojure, which then lead me to (re)discover Emacs and that lead me to SLIME.

I have a fairly decent handle on Emacs itself, and I have the emacs-starter-kit as well as clojure-mode/slime/swank as well as a few other unrelated modes and tweaks setup and running.

But setting up a program and understanding its capabilities are not the same. So now before I get back into experimenting with Clojure I'd like to first figure out a 
little more about the Slime IDE itself and what it can do.

Can anyone recommend a tutorial/screencast which will teach me some fundamental Slime usage? I am already familiar with executing Clojure interactively with Slime, but 
surely that cant be Slime's only feature.

The tutorial doesn't need to involve Clojure but if it does then that would be a 
plus, but the main focus of my interest is Slime so please don't post Clojure 
tutorials unless they highlight Slime usage beyond merely executing Clojure code interactively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really liked Marco Barringer's SLIME movie when I started out:

http://www.guba.com/watch/3000054867

Also, having a transcript of it helps:

http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/articles/reference-for-the-slimelispemacs-screencast/

I also found Bill Clementson's post helpful but it's more about set-up and not usage.

http://bc.tech.coop/blog/081205.html

Comment: thanks Seth, that is the type of thing I was looking for and the transcript really helps

Answer (score 2):

You could do worse than read the SLIME manual.  On my system (Ubuntu), it is located at `/usr/share/doc/slime/slime.pdf`.

Comment: This is also available in HTML format from the slime homepage: http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Marco's video to start.

There are links to it from the following along with another video that may be worth checking out.

http://www.cliki.net/Lisp%20Videos

Answer (score 0):

There is a short tutorial on SLIME available at http://lisp-book.org/contents/chslime.pdf. I found the section on the inspector very cool and useful.